# Android date picker date not selecting

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have added a date picker which is show once user clicks a view and date picker appears and user can select date on some devices date picker is not showing properly and user is unable to select date. Below screenshot is from Samsung J7 Android version 7.1.1.
[image]

code i'm using for date picker is this

```
public void initDatePicker(final TextView textView) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
            Date date = new Date();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            // and get that as a Date
            Date dateSpecified = c.getTime();
            if (dateSpecified.before(date)) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_date)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                UIHelper.showShortToastInCenter(this, "Selected Date is in Past");
            } else {
                
                DateSelected = dateSpecified;
                String predate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MMM d").format(c.getTime());
                String predateNew = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
                textView.setText(predate);
                textView.setPaintFlags(Typeface.BOLD);
                dateStr = predateNew;
                
            }
        },
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        Calendar min = Calendar.getInstance();
        min.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(min.getTimeInMillis());
        Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
        max.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 30);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(max.getTimeInMillis());
        dialog.getDatePicker().setEnabled(true);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

here is the theme of activity

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: did you try to set different colors for colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent?

Comment: nope but let me try

Comment: nothing changed, still smae

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the above issue, using basic dialog picker i was unable to change accent color of piker, i used a [Material Date/Time picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) which allows customisation of both date and time picker. below is the snippet which helped me fixing the issue

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dialog =  DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this::onDateSet,//Listener when user select date
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), // Initial year selection
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), // Initial month selection
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) // Initial day selection
    );
    dialog.setMinDate(calendar);
    Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
    max.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 30);
    dialog.setMaxDate(max);
    dialog.setAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DatePicker");
```